Spikes test NVMe
By chance I did a benchmark test of an NVMe that I have in a RAID. Are all these spikes normal? (the disk only causes problems if the power goes out and it doesn't turn off correctly = grub problem).


Grub is an OS boot loader so I do not see how you equate that to a power failure on a hard disk. More details please.

This performance is consistent with a single Gen4 x1 NVMe or a single Gen3 x2 NVMe drive which is relatively low end for modern NVMe but still much faster than SATA.  Depending on what type of RAID you're using you might have expected higher performance.
The spikes are not a particular cause for concern, particularly because there are no latency spikes - the latency is consistently very low.  There could be multiple explanations for the spikes, but it's probably specific to the internal behavior of the drive's controller.
